# Corona SDK - Movieclip framerate

Tags: animation, coronasdk

How can i set framerate in a movieclip inside corona sdk? I have a normal movieclip but i want a slower animation. I cant find api documentation about movieclip.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

a way to improve @krs answer if you want pass a parameter:

```
  local function callNextFrame(target) 
    target:nextFrame() 
  end 

  function play_anim( event ) 
    local listener = function() return callNextFrame( event.target ) end 
    timer.performWithDelay(100,listener,24) 
  end
```

reference: http://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/timer/performWithDelay.html

Answer (score 2):

You can use `myAnim:nextFrame()` with the help of a `timer` for this purpose. Try the following code:

```
local movieclip = require("movieclip")

local myAnim = movieclip.newAnim{"cube1.png", "cube2.png", "cube3.png", "cube4.png", "cube5.png", "cube6.png"}
myAnim.x = 160
myAnim.y = 240
localGroup:insert( myAnim )
```

For fast transition between frames, you can use:

```
local function callNextFrame()
   myAnim:nextFrame()
end
timer.performWithDelay(10,callNextFrame,-1)
```

For slow transition between frames, you can use:

```
local function callNextFrame()
  myAnim:nextFrame()
end
timer.performWithDelay(1000,callNextFrame,-1)
```

for further info, visit:

1) [Improved movieclip library](http://www.coronalabs.com/blog/2010/06/01/improved-movieclip-library/)

2) [MovieClip - corona labs](http://developer.coronalabs.com/content/movieclip)

Keep coding.............. :)

Answer (score 2):

Movieclip is deprecated in favor of imageSheets and Sprites where you can have better control over the timing.  There is a variant of movieclip.lua out there that lets you specify a delay, but it's an unsupported version.